# objective-c multi-dimensional array

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array

I want to use a variable-sized multi-dimensional array in my app to save data.  The data structure I want to use is as below, the first element in each  row is followed by corresponding multiple values.

```
 array = {   {a, a_val1, a_val2, a_val3}.  
             {b, b_val1},  
             {c, c_val1, c_val2, c_val3, c_val4, c_val5}  
         }
```

Any idea how I can implement in objective-c?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Objective-C does not have a real 2 dimensional array type but you can implement it with the 
    following codes..

in your header file --- yourheader.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface yourheader : NSObject{

    NSMutableDictionary* DictionaryArrayType;
    NSMutableArray* MultiArrayType;
    NSArray* CaptionTitle;
    NSArray* ObjectValue;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary* DictionaryArrayType;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* CaptionTitle;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* ObjectValue;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* MultiArrayType;

-(id) AddArrayObjects:(NSString*)_Name : (NSString*)_Surname :(NSString*)_Age;

-(id) AddArrayDictionaryObject:(NSArray*)_ArrayObject : (NSArray*)_ArrayKey;

-(id) AddMultiArrayType:(id)_ArrayObject;

-(void) ShowMultiArrayType:(id)_ArrayObject;

@end
```

Now add to your objective-c file ---- objective-c.m

```
#import "yourheader.h"

@implimentation yourheader

@synthesize DictionaryArrayType;

@synthesize CaptionTitle;

@synthesize ObjectValue;

@synthesize MultiArrayType;


-(id)init {

    if(self = [super init]){

        NSString* const NAME = @"NAME";
        NSString* const SURNAME = @"SURNAME";
        NSString* const AGE = @"AGE";
        //Adding fixed content to CaptionTitle Array
        [self setCaptionTitle:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NAME, SURNAME, AGE, nil]];

        //add values to ObjectValue array
        [self AddArrayObjects:@"Bob" :@"Obi" :@"200"];

        //add values to dictionary
        [self AddDictionaryArrayType:ObjectValue :CaptionTitle];

        //Add to the Multi dimensional array [][]
        [self AddMultiArrayType:DictionaryArrayType];  

        //add the second row values to ObjectValue array
        [self AddArrayObjects:@"Barack" :@"Obama" :@"50"]; 

        //add values to dictionary
        [self AddDictionaryArrayType:ObjectValue :CaptionTitle];

        //Add to the Multi dimensional array [][]
        [self AddMultiArrayType:DictionaryArrayType];  

        //display the 2d Array
        [self ShowMultiArrayType:MultiArrayType];

    }

    return self;
}


-(id)AddArrayObjects:(NSString *)_name :(NSString *)_surname :(NSString *)_age {

    //Set the Array Objects;
    [self setObjectValue:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:_name, _surname, _age, nil]];

    return self;

}

-(id)AddDictionaryArrayType:(NSArray *)_ArrayObject :(NSArray*)_ArrayKey {

    if(!DictionaryArrayType) {
        //initialize disctionary
        [self setDictionaryArrayType:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
    }
    //add array obeject and Fixed Key decleared in CaptionTitle array
    DictionaryArrayType = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:_ArrayObject forKeys:_ArrayKey];
    return self;
}

-(id) AddMultiArrayType:(id)_ArrayObject {

    if(!MultiArrayType) {

        [self setMultiArrayType:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }

    [MultiArrayType addObject:_ArrayObject]; 

    return self;
}

-(void)ShowMultiArrayType:_ArrayObject {

    for(id objects in _ArrayObject ) {

        for(id key in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@ key = : object =  %@", key, [objects objectForKey:key]);

        }
    }
}


@end;
```

To finish add this to your appdelegate.m file inside the app

```
  yourclassname* _yourclasspointer = [[yourclassname alloc] init];

 [_youclasspointer ShowMultiArrayType:[_yourclasspointer MultiArrayType]];
```

You should see it in you console.

Comment: Your solution ignores objective c language conventions such as beginning property names with a lowercase letter, naming all your method parameters and always using getter and setter methods for declared properties

Answer (score 15):

use NSMutableArray like so

```
NSMutableArray *curRow; /* use to access the row while loading with objects */
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; /* your main multidim array */
curRow = [NSMutableArray array];
[curRow addObject:/* what you want here */];
[curRow addObject:/* what you want here */];
[curRow addObject:/* what you want here */];
[array addObject:curRow]; /* first row is added */

/* rinse and repeat */
curRow = [NSMutableArray array];
[curRow addObject:/* what you want here */];
[curRow addObject:/* what you want here */];
[curRow addObject:/* what you want here */];
[array addObject:curRow];
```

Comment: Thank you - this is perfect.  I am going to mark this as my answer because it offers a generic solution - for creating a dynamic array at run time.  The next answer shows usage for a fixed size array.

Comment: This answer is so much better

Comment: To call a specific object, you can call the row it's on (the first set of "cur row" would be 0, the second set is 1, etc.) Then call the "addObject" (column) number it is... the first "addObject" is "0", the second is "1", etc.
`[[array objectAtIndex:/*Row Number*/] objectAtIndex:/*column number*/];`

Comment: `[(NSMutableArray *)[array objectAtIndex:/*X*/] objectAtIndex:/*Y*/];`

Answer (score 5):

use [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/)

Below is the example for your understanding ...

```
NSMutableArray * multiArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
[multiArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:a,a_val1,a_val2]];
[multiArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:a,a_val1,a_val2,a_val3,a_val4]];
[multiArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:a,a_val1,a_val5]];
[multiArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:a,a_val1,a_val2,a_val3,a_val4,a_val5,a_val6]];
```

**And** Don't forget to release to `multiArray`  array because we have `alloced` it ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer....but I was looking for idea for creating a dynamic multi-dimension array at runtime.  The prior answer was perfect for that.

Comment: @Sam Why do you think this method can't also be used at runtime?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw, this answer is similar to bigkm's, and it could be used at runtime. However, it requires that you have the subarray's objects available to add in advance (arrayWithObjects:...). If, say, you don't know how many objects you will have in a given subarray initially, then bigkm's answer allows the objects to be created and added 'on-the-fly'.