# Multidimensional array issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios5

I am creating a multidimensional array for sections / rows based on json data from our API. Looking at the logs the adding rows and sections look good but when I nslog the sections it only shows a bunch of the last object. It seems like the rows are not being added to sections.

What am I doing wrong to make the last API object show in the sections x times? x represents the json count.  `self.appointments` is an `NSArray *`

According to [objective-c multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459931/objective-c-multi-dimensional-array) it should work.

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSMutableArray *sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *lastDate = nil;
        for (NSDictionary *dict in [json objectForKey:@"data"]) {
            NSString *date = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];
            NSLog(@"Dates: %@ - %@", date, lastDate);
            if (date != lastDate) {
                if (lastDate == nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Adding Row 1");
                    [rows addObject:dict];
                    lastDate = date;
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Adding Section 1");
                    NSLog(@"Adding #rows %i",[rows count]);
                    [sections addObject:rows];
                    [rows removeAllObjects];
                    NSLog(@"Adding Row 2 %@",[dict objectForKey:@"start_time"]);
                    [rows addObject:dict];
                    lastDate = date;
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Adding Row 3");
                [rows addObject:dict];
            }
        }
        if (rows) {
            NSLog(@"Adding Section 2");
            NSLog(@"Adding #rows %i",[rows count]);
            [sections addObject:rows];
        }
        NSLog(@"Sections: %@", sections);

        self.appointments = [sections mutableCopy]; //I have also tried self.appointments = sections

        sections = nil;
        rows = nil;
```

Logs show

```
Sections: (
        (
                {
            abbrev = "";
            account = "";
            "addOnService_id" = "";
            alert = "";
            "appt_id" = 1839384;
            "appt_id_unique" = 1839384;
            "appt_status_description" = "";
            "appt_status_type" = "";
            "c_id" = 47;
            cost = "0.00";
            "coupon_id" = "";
            "creation_emp_id" = 2288;
            "creation_timestamp" = 201111040717;
            "customer_id" = 0;
            "customer_notes" = "";
            "customer_package_id" = "";
            date = 20121228;
            "employee_id" = 2288;
            "employee_notes" = "";
            employer = "";
            "end_time" = 570;
            "first_name" = "";
            "history_id" = 1830959;
            key = 134;
            "last_emp_id" = 2288;
            "last_name" = "";
            "last_timestamp" = 201111040717;
            "lead_description" = "";
            "link_id" = 0;
            "location_name" = "Telephonic Setup/Training";
            "make_id" = "";
            "middle_name" = "";
            "model_id" = "";
            "model_year" = "";
            name = "My Name ";
            odometer = "";
            "other_vehicle" = "";
            "package_name" = "";
            "payment_type_description" = "";
            "payment_type_id" = "";
            "pet_id" = "";
            "po_number" = "";
            reason = "B.O.B";
            "rebook_id" = "";
            "recur_id" = 20954;
            "rep_id" = "";
            "room_id" = 0;
            "room_name" = "";
            service = "";
            "service_id" = 0;
            "service_time_description" = "";
            spots = 1;
            "staff_screen_name" = "John Smith";
            "staff_type_id" = 0;
            "start_time" = 540;
            "status_id" = 0;
            tip = "";
            "type_id" = 8;
            vin = "";
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            abbrev = "";
            account = "";
            "addOnService_id" = "";
            alert = "";
            "appt_id" = 1839384;
            "appt_id_unique" = 1839384;
            "appt_status_description" = "";
            "appt_status_type" = "";
            "c_id" = 47;
            cost = "0.00";
            "coupon_id" = "";
            "creation_emp_id" = 2288;
            "creation_timestamp" = 201111040717;
            "customer_id" = 0;
            "customer_notes" = "";
            "customer_package_id" = "";
            date = 20121228;
            "employee_id" = 2288;
            "employee_notes" = "";
            employer = "";
            "end_time" = 570;
            "first_name" = "";
            "history_id" = 1830959;
            key = 134;
            "last_emp_id" = 2288;
            "last_name" = "";
            "last_timestamp" = 201111040717;
            "lead_description" = "";
            "link_id" = 0;
            "location_name" = "Telephonic Setup/Training";
            "make_id" = "";
            "middle_name" = "";
            "model_id" = "";
            "model_year" = "";
            name = "My Name ";
            odometer = "";
            "other_vehicle" = "";
            "package_name" = "";
            "payment_type_description" = "";
            "payment_type_id" = "";
            "pet_id" = "";
            "po_number" = "";
            reason = "B.O.B";
            "rebook_id" = "";
            "recur_id" = 20954;
            "rep_id" = "";
            "room_id" = 0;
            "room_name" = "";
            service = "";
            "service_id" = 0;
            "service_time_description" = "";
            spots = 1;
            "staff_screen_name" = "John Smith";
            "staff_type_id" = 0;
            "start_time" = 540;
            "status_id" = 0;
            tip = "";
            "type_id" = 8;
            vin = "";
        }
    ), ... over and over again.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
[sections addObject:rows];
[rows removeAllObjects];
[rows addObject:dict];
```

you keep adding the same `rows` object not a new one and keep changing the contents so the last contents display each time.

Try:

```
[sections addObject:[rows mutableCopy]]; 
[rows removeAllObjects];
[rows addObject:dict];
```

That way a new row is added each time.

Perhaps better yet:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *lastDate = nil;
for (NSDictionary *dict in [json objectForKey:@"data"]) {
    NSString *date = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];
    if ([date isEqualToString:lastDate] == NO) {
        if (lastDate == nil) {
            [rows addObject:dict];
            lastDate = date;
        } else {
            [sections addObject:rows];
            rows = [NSMutableArray array];
            [rows addObject:dict];
            lastDate = date;
        }
        [rows addObject:dict];
    }
}
if (rows) {
    [sections addObject:rows];
}

self.appointments = sections;
```

Note that assigning 0 to an object does not release it, `release` does. But if you use convenience methods to create objects then they are autoreleased and no further action is necessary to release them.

Also note that when comparing strings one needs to use the `isEqualToString:` method to compare the contents, just using the `=` or `!=` only compares the address of the strings.

Comment: that worked :) what exactly is mutableCopy for? Also it seems after about 2 months of dates it starts creating a section for each row even though the sections are the same but the start_times are different.

Comment: I assume it was setting the last one because i was using reference pointers and unsetting teh rows array. Correct?

Comment: The `mutableCopy` could be `copy` depending upon the further usage. The point is to create a new array. Adding an object to an array just adds the point (and ups the retain count), adding the same object multiple times just adds the same pointer and thus the same contents each time. The last contents is what is seen.

Comment: I edited your code post to include the `[sections addObject:[rows mutableCopy]];` you mentioned earlier.

Comment: In the Perhaps better code `[rows mutableCopy]` is not needed because the next line creates a new array, that is kind of the point of the example and convenience methods to create objects then they are autoreleased. Thus I rolled back the edits.