# How to parse NSDictionary into array of arrays?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

[here](http://pastebin.com/jC0chECY) is my data pattern and i want to create an array of sections, in which case, each section will include an array of rows in that section. I looked at the following questions:

- [2D arrays using NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724772/2d-arrays-in-objective-c)
- [objective-c multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459931/objective-c-multi-dimensional-array)

and a few other posts but could get no result. Can anyone please guide me how to create an array of sections, and each section shall include its own rows.. Thanks in advance

**EDIT** 
I have allready parsed my data, the log result at the pastebin link is an NSDictionary
here is how i fetch&parse it:

```
 NSString*key1=[ result objectForKey:@"key" ];                
         NSString *s1=[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:server.text];
         NSString *s2=[s1 stringByAppendingString:@"/ipad/button.php"];
         NSURL *url2=[NSURL URLWithString:[s2 stringByAppendingString:[@"?key=" stringByAppendingString:key1]]];

        NSData *data2=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2];
         result2=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data2 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

The result in pastebin is this: `NSLog(@"Result: %@", result2);`

Comment: @Jack, i followed your answer but couldnt get any result, can u give some more help please?

Comment: I didn't give any answer, I only reformatted your question

Comment: ah sorry, the third answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724772/2d-arrays-in-objective-c) one has been given by someone called Jack. i tought he is you:)

Comment: Is result2 a valid dictionary object?

Comment: result2 contains two main variables, one called version, which is a single number, and an array of arrays(the elements of inner array are dictionaryies..).. it is something like this;
buttonVersion:(some_number), template{Category1:(obj1,obj2...);Category2:( obj1, obj2...)...} i hope the scenerio is clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is in JSON format, so just use the `NSJSONSerialization` class to create the array of arrays for you.

```
NSString *yourData;
NSData *data = [yourData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *arrayOfArrays = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
    options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
```

To use your array of sections in a table view, just use the usual table view `datasource` methods:

```
// numberOfSectionsInTableView
return [array count];

// numberOfRowsInSection
return [[array objectAtIndex:section] count];

// cellForRowAtIndexPath
cell.textLabel.text = [[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] 
   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
      objectForKey:"name"];
```

Comment: i have already parsed data with NSJSONSerialization, but i shall try your code

Comment: Then use an error variable `NSError *error;` like this `...error:&error]; NSLog(@"%@", error);` and see what it says.

Comment: Then please log what your string, your data, your array and your error is - the mistake will become apparent.

Comment: please see my edit, i have allready used NSJSONSerialization before. what can i do from this point?

Comment: Congratulation, you have solved the problem. Now all you need to do is to check the check mark... For using the sections and rows in the tableview, see my edit.

Comment: the content of your array is still null.. that is the problem:)

Comment: i mean NSString *yourData;
NSData *data = [yourData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *arrayOfArrays = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
    options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil]; does nothing

Comment: You did not tell us what your log statements said about string, data, array and error. Analyze those and you will find the mistake.

Comment: i tried both error and a arrayOfArrays but they are still null, i copy&pasted your code exactly under mine. i couldnt understand why you declared the NSString variabl

Comment: Put your JSON into the string variable - come on, you can't just blindly copy code without thinking! That's not what SOF is for.

Comment: i do know i cant but i tried my data(which is data2) variable instead of yours. the result is sam

Comment: i have shared the code to .can you please say what i must do? i have initialized nsstring with my response data(result2) but nothing happened

Comment: It is clearly a problem with `dataWithContentsOfURL`. You should open a new question for this.